# how to use separate karate-config-<env>.js files

Tags: karate

I am trying to use separate `karate-config-<env>.js` file placed in karate-config directory using command prompt:

> mvn clean test
>   -Dkarate.config.dir="D:\Users\KhanAb\Photon-workspace\KarateAPI_MEMT\src\test\java\karate-config
>   karate-config-test.js" -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=test"

I am getting error because karate is unable to read `karate-config-test.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path seems wrong, there is a space before `karate-config-test.js`

Read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-specific-config

If you still have issues, be specific. If you are still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue